# Adding Custom Attribute in Configurable product

Tags: catalog, product, attributes, admin, configurable-product

This might be a very easy question for you, but its what I am wandering for hours..

MY issue is, I have a configurable product `'PRODUCT-1'` with custom attribute `SIZE`..now I want to add an other custom attribute `COLOR` in my product..

One way I know is, go from scratch, delete the preivous product and add new product with 2 attributes...This will not serve me better in my case..

Is there a way, I can add one more **custom attribute** to an existing **configurable product** ??

Comment: Not without change in the database or extension. Didn't try it and I don't think this is a good idea, but: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43288/#t330918

Comment: The questions is confusing. There are also custom-options  (Tab custom options, where a user can enter free text for example) - I think you are talking about a configurable product and it's options? Please edit your question.

Comment: @Alex thanks for pointing out this to me...edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible via the Import/Export function.

1. Export the configurable product (**System > Import/Export > Export**) and filter by SKU
2. Edit the configurable product in the exported CSV to include the color attribute by updating these columns:

   `_super_products_sku, _super_attribute_code, _super_attribute_option, _super_attribute_price_corr`
3. Re-import the CSV (**System > Import/Export > Import**)
4. Your product should be updated.

**IMPORTANT:** you might need to apply [this fix](http://razoyo.com/main/?q=blog/magento-17-configurable-product-export-fix) to get configurable products exporting properly.